# js datatables sorts wrong after table rearranging

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) jquery plugin to make my tables sortable. I need to rearrange columns after the table is created to make it look more logical, but after that it still does sort, but the result looks random. I can't get it to work, although (at least I think so) I am initiating datatable after the rearrangement.

```
function initTable() {

    $('tr').each(function () {
        $('td:last', this).remove().insertAfter($('td:first', this));
    });

    var table = $('#dashTable').dataTable({
        "paging": false,
        "ordering": true,
        "info": true,
        "order": [[0, "asc"]]
    });
    fixHeader(table);
}
```

If I don't call `$('tr').each` everything works as expected.

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to reorder the columns *after* the dataTable is initialized, then I strongly recommend you are using the [**ColReorder**](https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.3.0/) plugin.

```
var table = $('#dashTable').dataTable({
    ...
    colReorder: {
       order: [1, 5, 2, 3, 4] //alternative order
    }
});
```

If you just want to reorder the table columns before dataTables is initialized, then be sure to avoid asynchronicity traps by using a callback. As your code is constructed `dataTable({..})` is likely to be executed *before* the `each()` loop has finished :

```
var table;

function initTable() {

   function reorder(callback) {
     //good idea to include header titles when reordering
     $('thead tr').each(function () {
        $('th:last', this).remove().insertAfter($('th:first', this));       
     })
     var len = $('tbody tr').length;
     $('tbody tr').each(function () {
        $('td:last', this).remove().insertAfter($('td:first', this));
        if (!--len) callback();
     })  
   }   

   reorder(function() {
      table = $('#dashTable').dataTable({
        "paging": false,
        "ordering": true,
        "info": true,
        "order": [[0, "asc"]]
      });
      //fixHeader(table); guess this is the <th> reordering
   })   
}
```